# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token

Tags: c++, static-members

I have a class CompNum, which I need him to initialize the private static *crry* variable with the value of 0 (the variable **must** be private).

So I made a public function returning the reference of the crry variable, in order to be able to change that variable using the carry() function.

```
class CompNum {
private:
    typedef char littlenum;
    static littlenum crry;
    ...
public:
    static littlenum& carry() { /*Do something with crry*/ return crry; }
    ...
};

CompNum::carry() = 0;
```

Compiling this, it throws this error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
```

In the line:

```
 CompNum::carry() = 0;
```

**GOAL:**

The goal here is to be able to change the crry variable, but I need to make some things first every time I want to change it, so doing `CompNum::crry = 123` is not a solution, that's why I think I need a public method to achieve that.

Comment: Did you mean to write `littlenum CompNum::carry() { return 0; }`?

Comment: Is the line intended to deal with the `carry` function or the `crry` data memember?

Comment: @JamesAdkison With the crry data member

Comment: @Garmekain Then you need to specify the type `CompNum::littleenum`, it is not a function so no parens `()`, and you incorrectly used `carry` instead of `crry`.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: OP's class is written just fine, he just needs to define storage for the static class member.

Comment: @AndyG My interpretation was they the OP was trying to define the storage and initialize the value to `0`, not set the value using the reference returned by the `carry` function. But your interpretation may be correct. If so, what is the point of making `crry` private if it can be modified via a public `static` function? (rhetorical)

Comment: @AndyG I re-read the question and you're absolutely correct.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: haha, good point! In the context of this contradiction, your interpretation is quite reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a `static` member variable, you are really only specifying that it exists, but not creating storage for it. You need to "define" it outside the class:

```
CompNum::littlenum CompNum::crry;
```

---

Full Code:

```
class CompNum {
private:
    typedef char littlenum;
    static littlenum crry;
public:
    static littlenum& carry() { /*Do something with crry*/ return crry; }
};
CompNum::littlenum CompNum::crry;

int main()
{
   CompNum::carry() = 0;
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d72e313b9b439c53)